# Replace the last comma with dot

Tags: xml, xslt

output string (for example) is "12,236,15".
***I cannot change into the system format or type string.***

**Expected result:**
12356.15

I use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate('12,236,15', ',','.'), '#.00')"/>
```

It works well with strings containing just one 'comma' symbol.
Can I change just one symbol to 'dot' from the end?

The end can come as '12,236,156' (with 3 numbers), so fixed substring doesn`t match.

Comment: This is confusing. If "12,236,15" stands for 12356.15, what does '12,236,156' represent? IOW, what is the logic here? -- Also, you mention regex; does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I don`t have access to ASP.NET code, from some reason sometimes  I got into XML string like these '12,236,156', '14,452'.
Regarding to XSLT 2.0 yes.
I want to clarify is it possible or this is the bug and another department should fix it first.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to clarify is it possible or this is the bug and another department should fix it first.

Both. Using a comma for both the decimal and the thousands separator is definitely not a good way to represent a number.

Still, this seems to be working in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="replace(input, ',(\d*)$', '.$1')" />
<xsl:variable name="number" select="translate($number, ',', '')" />
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($number, '#.00')"/>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifp4